# enabling logging to log details of each user file opened on system

Tags: logging, arch

running Arch linux Kernel 5.10.56-1-lts. If I opened a text file called workflows.txt yesterday using my text editor application called 'geany'. How do I check what time the file was opened? I tried doing:

```
journalctl /usr/bin/geany
```

That didn't return any results. Presumably, this level of logging is currently not enabled on my system. How do I enable it?

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out.

Installed 'audit' using:

```
sudo pacman -S audit
```

Now I just need to create rules for files and directories that need auditing.

Arch wiki has all the details:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Audit_framework